# Asp.Net: ListView control doesn't show

Tags: asp.net, listview

i am trying to bring a ListView Control into my page, a basic blank plain one, without column names or other template features.

What i need is a blank list view where i could load rows with text from a textbox, extracted and loaded via server side.

In Asp.Net 3.5 requirements it seems i have to set up the `<LayoutTemplate>` and `<ItemTemplate>`, even though i don't need them for my specific task.

I tried this simple piece of code just to see what could happen, but nothing gets printed on the aspx page. 
If i get rid of the two template properties still nothing gets printed on screen.

I may have missed some basic configuration property, could someone give me some advices?

thanxalot

```
 <asp:ListView ID="LView" runat="server">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                <table>
                    <th>
                        string
                    </th>

                </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                     <tr> 
                      <td>
                        string
                      </td>
                     </tr> 
                 </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Noticed a "asp.net-mvc" tag, this question wasn't about using this server side control in a MVC view was it?

Answer (score 1):

ListView requires you to bind some data to it for it to render something.  Take a look at this article which walks you through using the ListView control.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24570/Complete-ListView-in-ASP-NET-3-5

Note that I found this with a quick Google search, I'm sure there are better tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Little sample:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FileStream f = new FileStream(ResolveUrl("~/HelloWorld.txt"), FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f);
        string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        ListView lv = new ListView();
        Table t = new Table();
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        tc.Text = content;
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        t.Rows.Add(tr);
        lv.Controls.Add(t);
        this.form1.Controls.Add(lv);

    }
}
```

Updated: added actual control to the page, sorry.
Good luck!